# Set font.color if month value is the same

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i can't make this block of code to work

```
Dim rng As Range, cll As Range

Set rng = Range("January")   ' I defined custom range with name January
For Each cll in rng
    If Month(cll) = Month(A7) Then   ' in A7 cell is date with January month in it
    cll.Font.ColorIndex = 5
    Else
    cll.Font.ColorIndex = 10
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `Month(A7)` by `Month([A7])`, or by `Month(Range("A7"))`, or by  `Month(Cells(7,"A"))`, or by `Month(Cells(7,1))`

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume that data appears in Sheet 1. Try the below code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TEST()

    Dim rngMonth As Range, cell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set rngMonth = .Range("January")

        For Each cell In rngMonth
            If Month(cell) = Month(.Range("A7")) Then
                cell.Font.ColorIndex = 5
            Else
                cell.Font.ColorIndex = 10
            End If
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```